# Tirar tabulação(tab) de varchar

Tags: sql, firebird

Boa tarde pessoal!
Estou tentando de todas as formas, porém não consigo tirar um tab no final de um varchar no firebird.
Alguém sabe como fazer?

Desde já, obrigado.

Editando para ficar mais específico:

Ex.:

```
    select guia, convenio, nome, trim(matricula) from tabela  where guia = '142'

    group by guia, convenio, nome, trim(matricula)
```

o Resultado

```
    142 | 1 | Nome do paciente | 111222
    142 | 1 | Nome do paciente | 111222
```

Porém, se eu retirar o campo matrícula, que é um varchar(40) que está com os tabs:

```
    select guia, convenio, nome from tabela  where guia = '142'

    group by guia, convenio, nome
```

O Resultado é:

```
   142 | 1 | Nome do paciente
```

E como eu descobri que o problema era da matricula:

Com a ajuda desta função: Char_Length(matricula)

```
    select guia, convenio, nome, Char_Length(matricula) from tabela  where guia = '142'

    group by guia, convenio, nome, matricula
```

O resultado:

```
    142 | 1 | Nome do paciente | 111222 | 6
    142 | 1 | Nome do paciente | 111222 | 10
```

Comment: Você já tentou o seguinte? `REPLACE('MINHA STRING COM TAB ', ' ', '')`. Se não der certo cola aqui o varchar de exemplo

Comment: já tentei sim, não deu certo, tentei com Trim tb... vou editar a pergunta pra ficar mais claro.
Obrigado

Comment: Você precisa copiar o texto que está errado e colar. Não adianta você falar que é um `TAB`, temos que ver com o código do caracter pra ter certeza

Comment: O código do caracter não aparecia, só percebi que era um tab através de engenharia reversa, mesmo assim, obrigado, consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui da seguinte maneira:

```
trim(both from replace(campo, ascii_char(9), ' '))
```

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar isso:

```
SELECT guia, convenio, nome, TRIM(REPLACE(matricula, '\t', ' '))
FROM tabela
WHERE guia = '142'
GROUP BY guia, convenio, nome, TRIM(REPLACE(matricula, '\t', ' '))
```

Comment: não funcionou, amigo... tudo na mesma... pra dizer a verdade, testei e nem o trim está funcionando, com espaços simples...tá estranho...